# Using Pandas to get a specific value in .csv cell for graphing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a time vs window size graph. I have a CSV file with a time and info heading.
My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv(r"path\file.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Time', 'Info'])
print(df)
```

This leaves me with the output:

```
          Time                                               Info
0     0.000000  41474 > dhanalakshmi [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len...
1     0.154122  dhanalakshmi > 41474 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Wi...
2     0.204863  41474 > dhanalakshmi [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=296...
3     0.222486  41474 > dhanalakshmi [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Wi...
4     0.234292  41474 > dhanalakshmi [ACK] Seq=2049 Ack=1 Win=...
```

How would I go about getting the Window size value (Win=XXXX) and plotting it vs the time column?

Comment: `plt.plot(df.Time, df.Info.str.extract('Win=([\d]+)').astype(float))`?

Comment: This is correct, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
plt.plot(df.Time, df.Info.str.extract('Win=([\d]+)').astype(float))
```